# Return maximum value from a multi-dimensional array (ndarray)

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, game-theory

So I have the following code:

```
import numpy
import nash

pool_of_games = [[[0,2,1,3,3,2,1,0],"PdPd","PrisonerDilemma"], 
[[0,3,1,2,2,3,1,0],"ShSh","StagHunt"],
[[1,2,3,0,3,2,1,0],"ChCh","Chicken"],
[[2,1,0,3,3,1,0,2],"BaBa","Battle"]]

def RandomStrategySelection343(pool_of_games):   
    gci = 0   
    fitness_list = []
    nash_pool = [] 
    for game in range (0, len(pool_of_games)):    
        pr1 = pool_of_games[game][0][:2]   
        pr2 = pool_of_games[game][0][2:4]
        pc1 = pool_of_games[game][0][4:6]
        pc2 = pool_of_games[game][0][6:]
        p1_strategy_vector = [pr1, pr2]
        p2_strategy_vector = [pc1, pc2]
        game_matrix = nash.Game(p1_strategy_vector,p2_strategy_vector)
        print(game_matrix)
        nash_array = game_matrix.support_enumeration()
        nash_list = list(nash_array)
        print("NL",nash_list)
        for s1,s2 in nash_list:
            row_utility = ((numpy.dot(numpy.dot(s1,p1_strategy_vector),s2)))
            print(row_utility)
            col_utility = (numpy.dot(numpy.dot(s1,p2_strategy_vector),s2))
            print(col_utility)
            fitness = row_utility + col_utility
            print ("FS",fitness)
        maxfit = fitness.max()
        print ("MX", maxfit)
```

I am using the `numpy.dot` function here to obtain the product of two same-sized matrixes (created by the nash functions). I believe this function returns the data in an ndarray of data. What I do next is summing them up.

The (partial) output of the function, as an example, is:

```
Row player:
[[2 1]
 [0 3]]

Column player:
[[3 1]
 [0 2]]
NL [(array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 1.,  0.])), (array([ 0.,  1.]), array([ 0.,  1.])), (array([ 0.5,  0.5]), array([ 0.5,  0.5]))]
2.0
3.0
FS 5.0
3.0
2.0
FS 5.0
1.5
1.5
FS 3.0
MX 3.0
```

As you can see, the results and the sum are being computed correctly, however the **MAXIMUM** value (MX) is not. This would be the main result from this part of the code.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fitness` is not an array, it's a scalar to which you assign in a loop. First it's assigned 5; then 5 again, then 3. At the end of the loop `fitness` is 3. And the maximum of a single number 3 is of course 3.  The following would be a correct way to find the maximal fitness:

```
  maxfit = -np.inf   # negative infinity to initialize
  for s1,s2 in nash_list:
        row_utility = ((numpy.dot(numpy.dot(s1,p1_strategy_vector),s2)))
        col_utility = (numpy.dot(numpy.dot(s1,p2_strategy_vector),s2))
        fitness = row_utility + col_utility
        maxfit = max(fitness, maxfit)
  print(maxfit)
```

The main point is that `maxfit` is updated within the loop.